# Python If statement not printing anything

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm new to this site and this is my very first post. Can usually find answers by just typing in what I needed, but for this I don't know how to word the question. Trying to fix it still, have been for about an hour now, but don't know what's wrong.

My code is below, and when I run it all it does it print out the functions I have (npc and story) and the correct print statements for those, and then stops at the bottom where I have an infinite while loop doing nothing, and it seems to not even notice that the if statement (with the print "STORYSTORYSTORY") is there.

Here's my code:

```
while True:
    print "\n You wake up in a small room, the lights are dim and the only thing you can see is a table with a few gold pieces and a glass of water."
    input1 = raw_input ("What do you do?").lower()
    if input1 == "take gold":
        print "\n You take the gold and it's added to your inventory"
        time.sleep(3)
        npc("jenkins_gold")
        story("part1")
        loop == 2
        break
    if input1 == "drink water":
        print "\n You reach for the water, and gulp it down."
        time.sleep(3)
        npc("jenkins_water")
        story("part1")
        loop == 2
        break

if loop == 2:
    print "\n Story"
    print "\n STORYSTORYSTORY"

while True:
    y = 1
    x = y
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have the whole game running in a loop. There's the while loop at the bottom, just in case that has anything to do with it. If you need anything else from my code please let me know, I should respond within minutes. Thank you

Comment: What is the last while loop supposed to do?

Comment: It's unclear what's your asking. Please post the output you get and the output you expect.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't realize these comments were here, never saw them. My question was answered, and it's quite a useless question to everyone else, do I delete it or change the title to solved, or accept an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first `while` statement: `loop == 2` evaluates to `True` (it's a boolean expression, because you used `==`) and does nothing else, you want to affect `loop` with `2`, so you need to do `loop = 2` (it will be an assignment, because you will use `=`).

```
while True:
    print "\n You wake up in a small room, the lights are dim and the only thing you can see is a table with a few gold pieces and a glass of water."
    input1 = raw_input ("What do you do?").lower()
    if input1 == "take gold":
        print "\n You take the gold and it's added to your inventory"
        time.sleep(3)
        npc("jenkins_gold")
        story("part1")
        loop = 2
        break
    if input1 == "drink water":
        print "\n You reach for the water, and gulp it down."
        time.sleep(3)
        npc("jenkins_water")
        story("part1")
        loop = 2
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign 2 to `loop` via the equality operator `==`. Instead, assign it with the assignment operator `=` like this:

```
loop = 2
```